# .keystore deleted by accident

Tags: java, jar, certificate, jar-signing

I'm trying to sign a JAR file.  I generated a new store using the

```
"keytool -genkey -alias myStore -keystore mainstore"
```

And the store got generated with the actual name "mainstore" under my Windows user directory.

I then try to self sign the JAR file using

```
"jarsigner myApp.jar myStore".
```

But I'm getting error:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\myusername    \.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I looked and the .keystore file is not there.  I think it got deleted by accident.  Is there a way to generate a new .keystore file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [manual page for `jarsigner`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/jarsigner/) states:

> `jarsigner` has a `-keystore` option for specifying the name and location of the keystore to be used. The keystore is by default stored in a file named `.keystore` in the user's  home directory, as determined by the `user.home` system property.

Which means that in Windows, `C:\Users\myusername\.keystore` is the default keystore file.

So what you probably need to do is tell `jarsigner` where your keystore is located:

```
jarsigner -keystore mainstore myApp.jar myStore
```

Comment: jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\SaravanakumarNarayan\Documents\Ionic\ICOM%20Git\ICOM.ParentApp.IonicAngular\ICOM.ParentAppKeyStore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified) -- I have created new jks file and android sdk always refer to the old jks path. i tried your command but i don't know about jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file might not be deleted, I was having the same problem and updating to the latest jdk solved my problem.